# How to slide metal using electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields

Is it possible to slide a sheet of metal or amorphous foil in a direction between two electrodes using electromagnetism. Kind of like this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by amorphous foil? Is it also a conductor? The +- signs on the capacitor plates signify an applied voltage or just isolated charges or the plates?

Comment: Something like metglas with a high permeability, im really just trying to figure out if its possible with any material. Must be flat tho. Abit like this https://youtu.be/J9b0J29OzAU except not a coil and using flat sheets while not being a closed system.

Comment: Is it an insulator (dielectric) with high permittivity $\epsilon$? You are probably not meaning magnetic permeability $\mu$?

Comment: Well not too sure if I am honest. Yes it has an applied charge. Was thinking metglas could have added strength to the effect... as you would do with an iron core in a coil however now thinking about it I can see that doesn't make much sense. Really not sure what to use in the centre to make it slide using electromagnetism?

Comment: A metal sheet almost as thick as the distance between the electrodes would experience the strongest force. For a thick dielectric slab, the effect would increase with thickness and permittivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the electrodes are charged capacitor plates, thick sheets of metal or high permittivity dielectric would be drawn into the electrodes. Very thin foils (compared to the distance of the electrodes) would experience only a very small force. The reason is that the capacitor with inserted metal or high permittivity dielectric has a lower electrostatic potential energy with the sheets inserted than when they are outside. This produces a mechanical force drawing the sheets into the capacitor.

The forces can be easily derived by considering the change in electrostatic energy of the capacitor with partially inserted sheets which increases the capacitance of the system.

Comment: So it is possible? What kind of force?

Comment: This is an electrostatic force.

Comment: @GarrithGraham yes, this kind of electrostatic arrangement, although more sophisticated, is often used in MEMS actuation.

Comment: @Rod Vance I was looking at the lorentz force, can not believe you picked up on that from my drawing..